# Pass a database value to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I retrieved all of my friends' names which are currently online using MySQL joins and PHP.

Now I want to insert their names inside JavaScript for chatting with them.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith('Friend1')">Friend1 </a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith('Friend2')">Friend2 </a>
```

I am unable to do this. Because I don't know how to call JavaScript inside PHP or viceversa.

```
while($get_usernames=mysql_fetch_array($get_users_query)) {             
    echo '<br>'.$get_usernames['username'];                         
}
```

I want to show each of `$get_usernames['username']` as Friend1, Friend2, inside JavaScript

Comment: you are trying to access database that is on server from javascript that run on client side?? you need to call ajax that will fetch data from db and return result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
<?php
$aUsernames = array();
while($get_usernames=mysql_fetch_array($get_users_query)) {             
    array_push($aUsernames, $get_usernames['username']);                         
}
foreach($aUsernames as $name) {
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith('<?php echo $name; ?>')"><?= $name; ?> </a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Using AJAX is much neater ofcourse, but this will suffice if it is all in one PHP file.

Also I would like to encourage you to move to PDO or Mysqli since mysql functions are deprecated.

Comment: chrisblomm still some errors there, the javascript causing the error...
could you please rectify this, and post again..thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use AJAX to call a php page and get value from that.

Call the php page and after querying simply return value using `echo`. You can get that value using `responseText` in javascript

http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxphp.php

Comment: if he dont mind, probably using [jQuery for ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) would be much easier to learn.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic yes jquery is awesome simple and easier

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place some PHP variable inside javascript, a simple way of doing it is by simply using the php loop inside your page to create the a tags.

Something like this:

```
$aTagList = "";
while($get_usernames=mysql_fetch_array($get_users_query)) {             
    $aTagList .= "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='javascript:chatWith(\"".$get_usernames['username']."\")>".$get_usernames['username']."</a>";                         
}
```

Then echo the $aTagList wherever you need it in the page with some inline code.

```
<?php echo $aTagList; ?>
```

Not sure if I got all the escaping correct, but it should give you the right idea.

Comment: i can't echo $aTagList, it causing some side of page missing

Comment: What exactly is it causing? Is the php page that you are executing the query on the same that you are printing the a tags?